# Secure Azure hosting of an Office Add-in not working the first time

Tags: azure, outlook-addin, office-addins, office365-apps, office-js

I have created a sample Outlook Add-in and hosted the home.html and all the other files within an Azure static HTML5 site.

Without Authentication turned on the Add-in works just fine in O365 Mail. But once I turn on authentication the add-in does not work the first time.

[image]

Clicking on Retry or refreshing the whole page makes the add-in work because within this browser session you have authenticated with Azure and home.html loads just fine.

[image]

What I think might be happening is that authentication to Azure works just fine - but the OWA app then tries to load the authentication response and not the home.html page.

[image]

What am I missing and how can I get this to work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but one thing you can check is the loading duration of your plugin.
If a plugin is not loaded after 5 secs (not sur if it's 5 or 3...) the add in is automaticaly placed in error state.

You should see the duration with a fiddler trace.

If it's your problem, be sure to :

- Minify all your javascript files to load faster.
- Be sure to NOT doing some weird stuff before your welcome page is loaded. Wait after your document is loaded to do anything else.

Sébastien

Comment: Sébastien - thanks for the response, appreciate it - the add in actually works just fine if authentication is turned off - Logging in is apparently a problem. Still not solved this :(